# LyX and Git for version control

Tags: lyx, git, revision-control

I can’t make LyX work with Git.

I followed the guidelines in section 7.2.6 in the "Additional Features" LyX manual, but once the git repo is created for the document, and I try to `register` my document with LyX GUI I get the following error:

```
Some problem occurred while running the command:
'ci -q -u -i -t-"First draft " "grand_écrit.lyx"'.
```

And then a `Lyx crashed error message` saying:

```
SIGSEGV signal caught!
Sorry, you have found a bug in LyX, hope you have not lost any data.
Please read the bug-reporting instructions in 'Help->Introduction' and send us a bug report, if necessary. Thanks!
Bye
```

With the following details:

```
  1) /usr/bin/lyx: /usr/bin/lyx(+0x63d1f8) [0x5603ffae41f8]
(  2) /usr/bin/lyx: /usr/bin/lyx(+0x63c652) [0x5603ffae3652]
(  3) /usr/bin/lyx: /usr/bin/lyx(+0x2feb27) [0x5603ff7a5b27]
(  4) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520) [0x7fcf88442520]
(  5) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5(+0x2f12a8) [0x7fcf88ef12a8]
(  6) /usr/bin/lyx: /usr/bin/lyx(+0x6cfd53) [0x5603ffb76d53]
(  7) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5(+0x2f17c8) [0x7fcf88ef17c8]
(  8) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: QAction::triggered(bool)
(  9) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: QAction::activate(QAction::ActionEvent)
( 10) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: QObject::event(QEvent*)
( 11) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)
( 12) /usr/bin/lyx: /usr/bin/lyx(+0x64edb0) [0x5603ffaf5db0]
( 13) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*)
( 14) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*)
( 15) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5(+0x313a67) [0x7fcf88f13a67]
( 16) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x26b) [0x7fcf88b1bd3b]
( 17) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0xaa6c8) [0x7fcf88b706c8]
( 18) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_iteration+0x33) [0x7fcf88b193e3]
( 19) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
( 20) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
( 21) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: QCoreApplication::exec()
( 22) /usr/bin/lyx: /usr/bin/lyx(+0x307c0d) [0x5603ff7aec0d]
( 23) /usr/bin/lyx: /usr/bin/lyx(+0x1a3939) [0x5603ff64a939]
( 24) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7fcf88429d90]
( 25) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7fcf88429e40]
( 26) /usr/bin/lyx: /usr/bin/lyx(+0x1af63e) [0x5603ff65663e]
```

It seems like LyX doesn’t detect the git repo as it is supposed to based on the documentation. I don’t know how to fix this.

I’m running Ubuntu 22.04, and downloaded LyX through the official Ubuntu repo. Here is the details of LyX:

```
LyX 2.3.6 (2020-11-27)
Configuration
  Host type:               x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  Special build flags:      build=release std-regex warnings use-enchant
  Bundled libraries:       (none)
  C++ Compiler:            g++ (10.2.0)
  C++ Compiler flags:       -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -O2 -std=c++14  -Wno-deprecated-copy
  C++ Compiler user flags:  -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -std=c++14  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/lyx-ufkcxK/lyx-2.3.6=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC
  Linker flags:            
  Linker user flags:       -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now
  Qt Frontend:
      Qt version:          5.15.2
  Packaging:               posix
  LyX binary dir:          /usr/bin
  LyX files dir:           /usr/share/lyx
```

Comment: Indeed LyX is not detecting the git repository for some reason (It still should not crash though). When you run LyX from the command line, run it like this: `lyx --verbose`. Then, in the terminal output I see this: `git ls-files "newfile1.lyx" > "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.kbwtpDwePlaA/lyxvcout.pZlSNq`. What do you see?

Comment: I get the following: `Running: git ls-files "grand_écrit.lyx" > "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.KCOYdfayrYeN/lyxvcout.xGRnBd"`. But then it runs `Running: git ls-files "grand_écrit.lyx" > "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.KCOYdfayrYeN/lyxvcout.xGRnBd"` and throws an error which is to be expected because it is most likely looking for RCS or CVS or SVN program.

Comment: Also, the crash did not occur this time.

Comment: Strange. I'm not sure what to suggest to try next. If you can't figure out a solution, I suggest you try writing to lyx-users@lists.lyx.org.

Comment: Will do, thanks. I’ll post the answer here if there is any coming up from the mailing list.

Comment: From the mailing list: "Essentially the problem is that "git init" is not enough for LyX to recognize
that the directory is under git control.
Once the first file is added via "git add" the recognition (of not just the file
but the whole dir) works and register command will proceed.
I'll try to look on that once I have some free time.
At the moment your workaround is to start new git repo via init + add file
on the commandline (or via some git frontend)." This is kind of works for now, although I still get some errors thrown at me somewhat randomly. Haven’t dug deeper yet.

Comment: The best way for now, I figured, is to use git from the command line and not interact with the LyX GUI.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. I suggest you add the 'git init' workaround as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Temporary solution

From the lyx-users@lists.lyx.org mailing list I got the following answer, which is a work around:

> Indeed I see your problem and we need to either update the code or guidelines.
>
> Essentially the problem is that "git init" is not enough for LyX to recognize that the directory is under git control.
>
> Once the first file is added via "git add" the recognition (of not just the file but the whole dir) works and register command will proceed. I'll try to look on that once I have some free time.
>
> At the moment your workaround is to start new git repo via init + add file on the commandline (or via some git frontend).

What works best for now, I figured, is to simply use the git command line and not fiddle with the LyX GUI.